# reduce all image in zip to be under fix (KB) using Imagemagick convert

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, compression, imagemagick-convert

I'm using Imagemagick , i'm wondiring how i can reduce inside zip all f.e `jpg` images inside and change their size be under `40K`.

Till now i've tried

according :

https://gist.github.com/rkbhochalya/d3557a9d122ab547c040af3adbd565c2

```
 find . -name "*.jpg" -exec convert -define jpeg:extent=40kb "{}" -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -colors 16 -depth 8  -define jpeg:extent=38kb "{}" \; -exec echo "{}" \;
```

but it only reduces bit rate and colors to 16 that is ok , but not enough.

tried `magick mogrify -strip -colors 16 -depth 8 -quality 90  assets/*.jpg`

but still I need to reduce under 40K each image

[image]

thanks,

Comment: 40K is rather small. If your file dimensions are too large, you will never get that low even at -quality of 1. But you can try using -define jpeg:extent={size}. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write. Or lower your quality value until you reach 40K if you can. I do not think Imagemagick will process inside zip files.

Comment: @fmw42 , see my question , it is what i used...it didn't work. it works only on specific file. i need on all files inside folder. I'm pretty sure i have a mistake in syntax. BTW, 40K is the demand for google ad-server

Comment: Post one of your JPG files so I can test. What is the width and height of your image? What is your IM version and platform and what is your version of libjpeg? Why do you have -define jpeg:extent twice. It should only be used after reading in the input file and before writing the output file. When using -colors you should add +dither before that to turn off dithering which will create new colors.

Comment: @ fmw42 , This command is works. convert ~/Desktop/test123.png  +dither -colors 16 -quality 85%  -type palette -depth 8 -define jpeg:extent=40kb out.png , but i need to run it recursively on all files in folder , do you have idea ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using mogrify rather than convert. It will process all images in a directory. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify.

But you will never get such a command to get 40K file size for PNGs unless your dimensions are very small. Try saving as JPG. The JPEG extent define only works for saving to JPG.

So for saving as JPG, if I have my images on the desktop in folder test1 and want to save to folder test2 on the desktop, I would do

```
cd
cd desktop/test1
mogrify -path ../test2 -format jpg -strip -depth 8 -define jpeg:extent=40kb *
```

If you really want to save as PNG, the best you could do would be (or reduce colors further)

```
cd
cd desktop/test1
mogrify -path ../test2 -format png -strip +dither -colors 16 -type palette -depth 8 *
```

But unless your images have very small width and height, neither will not get down to 40K. You could try adding -quality, but the quality values for PNG are different from JPG. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality

I think saving as JPG will give you the best chance.

Comment: @ fmw42 , added to question screenshot , it works partially , when the extension is PNG it reduces to 40K successfully , but when it JPEG, it not reduces to 40K. I've tried to change the extension to PNG , but still it doesn't work. I can share my images as example :)

Comment: Was it the same image that converted successfully to PNG, but not to JPG? Post a link to an example image that does not convert to JPG under 40K with my command above. Note that as per my examples above, you need two different commands, one for JPG output and one for PNG output.

Comment: shared a public link - need to run recursively and reduce to 40KB all works but jpg :):) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W07pQFfvH3kGsW_5zAnjpQzW3jCvE-FO

Comment: All your images converted to 40K or less as JPG output except 17_Glasses_NoHat_v04.jpg. The reason is that its width and height are too large, i.e., too many pixels. The processing tried to use quality 1, which is as low as it can get, but with quality 1, it is still larger than 40K. Note I forgot to add -strip to my commands in my post. I have edited it. But that still does not help that one image. I ran the other command to save as PNG, but all but one image was larger than 40K. The only way to get all your files to be smaller than 40K is to reduce the file dimensions and save to JPG

Comment: exactly what i say in the printscreen everything good except 1. maybe convert it to another format ? Btw, i used another online tool called https://compress-or-die.com , and it success to reduce below 40K !! ...what you suggest ? =]

Comment: To get all your files below 40K as JPG or PNG with Imagemagick, you will need to resize the image to some smaller dimensions (WxH) that will process to 40K or smaller. Some of your images have too many pixels to get the file size to be 40K or less.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190859/discussion-between-vitalyt-and-fmw42).